# Overlaying a UIView on UITableView and stick it beneath navigation bar on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement something similar as in this mockup: http://share.framerjs.com/16hwz94ezflt/ (scroll down)

If you scroll down the "week" view will stick beneath the navigation bar.
I have a similar UITableView with a header (above the "week" view).

It is not clear to me if this "week" view is part of the table view or not. It doesn't really matter but I'm really curious how one can implement something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do using autolayout constraints

1. Keep everything *but* the WeekView inside a UIScrollView/UITableView
2. Set up all of the items inside the scroll view
3. Create the WeekView as a UIView (Or something of the sort) and give it the following constraints:

   - A: Leading/trailing space set to container margin (could be the master view or the scroll view)
   - B: Specify a static height constraint
   - C: Add a constraint relating the top of the WeekView to the view above it (in this case the total SalesView), with the space set to 0. This constraint should make the week view follow the SaleView's position.
   - D: Add a constraint relating the top of the WeekView to the top of the grandparent view in the View Controller. This constraint will keep the WeekView at the top of the screen

Now obviously, the last 2 constraints conflict each other. What you do now is modify constraint D so that the relation is not = 0, but >= 0. Then, set constraint C's *priority* to less than 1000 (default), say 900. So constraint C can essentially break if another constraint (constraint D in this case) needs it to break.

What this will do is tell autolayout "okay, as long as WeekView is below the top it's cool. It can't go above the top. I also want it to be right below the position of SalesView, but if constraint D is like "Hey, back off", I'll back off"

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> It is not clear to me if this "week" view is part of the table view or not. It doesn't really matter but I'm really curious how one can implement something like this.

It certainly could be!

Your implementation may depend on whether you're using a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView`.

For a `UITableView`, the section in your example containing the horizontally-scrolling pages may be a `UITableViewHeader`. The sticky area containing the "week" view is a custom `UITableHeaderFooterView` that you'll define in [`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/).

For a `UICollectionView`, there's a little manual labor involved. The idea is fundamentally the same — one section contains a header (`UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`) that sticks to the navigation per your collection view layout definition. Look [here](https://gist.github.com/toblerpwn/5393460) and [here](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) for thoughts on that.

---

**Edit:** Here's a rough example to evaluate in a Playground.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

class StickyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView!
var items = ["1",
             "2",
             "3",
             "4",
             "5",
             "6",
             "7",
             "8",
             "9",
             "10",
             "11",
             "12",
             "13",
             "14",
             "15",
             "16",
             "17",
             "18",
             "19",
             "20",
             "21",
             "22",
             "23",
             "24",
             "25"
             ]


let tableViewHeader = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view!.frame, style: .Plain)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")

    tableViewHeader.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.width, 300)
    tableViewHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableViewHeader
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 0
    default:
        return items.count
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.width, 40))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: headerView.frame)
    headerLabel.text = "Label"
    headerLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return nil
    case 1:
        return headerView
    default:
        return headerView
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {


    switch section {
    case 0:
        return nil
    default:
        return " "
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(self.items[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
    }
}

let rootViewController = StickyTableViewController()

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

let page = XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage
page.liveView = navigationController.view
```

Comment: So how does the UITableHeaderFooterView stick to the top when you scroll down? Is this default behavior?

Comment: That's the default behavior for a `UITableView` with multiple sections. Assuming you only have a single section in your table, you can force this behavior by declaring the first section to be empty [1] and not have a header [2].

[1] See `numberOfRowsInSection`.
[2] See `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: @chrisdoukas thanks for the example. But what I want is for this section header to stay on top, even if you scroll past other sections.